# How not to escape debuggerPath of pipeTransport in launch.json

Tags: openshift, visual-studio-code

I'd like to do remote debugging from Visual Studio code to docker container on OpenShift.
In the previous version, I can do it with below launch.json.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [        
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Docker Remote Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "21",
        "pipeTransport": {
            "pipeProgram": "oc",
            "pipeArgs": [ "rsh", "remotedebug-1-mispn", "--"],
            "debuggerPath": "/opt/app-root/src/clrdbg/clrdbg",
            "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/opt/app-root/src": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it can't work well at the latest version 1.11.0-insider. This is because VSCode escaped debuggerPath with an option like below.

```
"oc" rsh remotedebug-1-mispn -- "/opt/app-root/src/clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi"
```

The oc exec command is similar to docker exec command. But the oc command recognizes "/opt/app-root/src/clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi" as a one file path. I'd like to execute below command.

```
"oc" exec remotedebug-1-mispn -- /opt/app-root/src/clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi
```

Could anyone give me an advice how to workaround this issue?

Comment: Can you just leave debuggerPath empty and add it as the final element of the pipeargs array? Those aren't being quoted

Comment: When I left debuggerPath empty or not specified, VS Code displays error message "attach: properties 'processId' and 'debuggerPath' needs to be specified with pipeTransport!".

Comment: I fount the same thing happens not only in "oc" command but also "docker" command. So I posted the GitHub issue and it has finally resolved.
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1318